# Has Many relations in between both models

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, yii

I have the database something like this

```
  == Invoices ==
  id
  customer_id

  == Customers ==
  id
  firstname
  lastname
  membersince
```

So I made relations in between both models like below.

Relation definition in the Invoices Model:

```
'customers'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Invoices','customer_id'),
```

Relation definition in the Customers Model

```
'invoices' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Invoices', 'invoice_id'),
```

Now I want to know the relation in between both models are correct? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the relation between the models is not correct.

I assume what you want here is that customers can have many invoices, but an invoice can only be owned by a single customer, as this is what your database schema implies.

*Please note that in the code below I distinguish between singular and plural forms of customer and invoice to make the code logical and easy to understand.*

In that case the relation definition in the `Invoice` model would be like this:

```
class Invoice extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'customer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Customer', 'customer_id')
        );
    }
}
```

The invoice 'belongs to' a customer. `'Customer'` indicates that the type of model we refer to is a `Customer`, and `'customer_id'` is the name of the column in the `invoices` table that refers to the primary key of the customer.

The `Customer` model looks a bit trickier:

```
class Customer extends CActiveRecord {
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'invoices' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Invoice', 
                               'customer_id', 'index' => 'id')
        );
    }
}
```

Here the relation definition indicates that a `Customer` can refer to many `Invoice` models. Notice how the rest of the relation is defined. `customer_id` is again the column that refers to a `Customer`, and `'index' => 'id'` tells Yii to use the column `id` in the `customers` table as key for the relationship.

You can find more information about the `relations` method in the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail).